# How to create a .pdf from a .pdf model?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, pdf, pdf-generation

I remember in Java, I was once able to create a .pdf from a model. I had to edit it first with Adobe and then I could do it. But is it possible to do that in Flutter?

I've been doing some research, but most of it is just creating the .pdf directly.

I hope to generate a .pdf from a .pdf model. Or rather, it could be like an "editor" of .pdf.